# how to remove the bullets getting displayed?

Tags: html, css, extjs

I'm running Ext JS code with the help of `ext-all.js`, `ext-all.css` and `ext-all.base`.

I don'want to display bullets in lists. Where and what do I have to modify? Do I need to make changes in CSS? Are CSS files responsible for all designs?

Comment: What kind of bullets are you talking about?

Comment: @chau:I'm executing an EXTJS code form a tree with expanding & compressing nodes.i'm very new to extjs.When i executed the code,tree got displayed but with bullets.but i don't want those bullets to b displayed.

Comment: Are you talking about the tree-node icons?

Comment: @master123: This is exactly the reason why you should post the code you are using to generate (in this case) the bullets. A combination of a description along with some code, will in many cases allow us to understand what you are doing :)

Comment: @ Chris: Yup.i've to get display the icons instead of those bullets.

Comment: @ chau : i'm unable to post the code since it exceeds the limits. what best i can do for that ????

Comment: @master123: use http://pastebin.com to post large fragments of code and link it here

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display bullets from an <ul> inside a panel body? The body of a panel gets a css-reset. You can prevent that by adding `preventBodyReset: true` to your panel config.

Check the documentation for more info: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Panel

Comment: @ Chris: Yup.i've to get display the icons instead of those bullets.